# Python Pandas Dropping First in Series of Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most Pythonic way to drop the only the first in a series of duplicates?

I have a dataframe:

```
Group    Value
  a        0
  a        1
  a        2
  b        6
  b        7
  b        8
```

and I want the following result:

```
Group    Value
  a        1
  a        2
  b        7
  b        8
```

`drop_duplicates` *keeps* the first or last item depending on how you set it.  I want to *drop* the first occurrance where there is a duplicate and keep the rest.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are no duplicates?

Comment: If there are no duplicates keep the row.

Comment: Do you care about contiguity?  Could there be a second group of as after the bs where you'd want to keep all but the first, or would they be counted as duplicates of the a and all kept?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `duplicated()` to create a boolean mask and filter based on it:

```
df[df.Group.duplicated()]

#Group  Value
#1   a      1
#2   a      2
#4   b      7
#5   b      8
```

`duplicated` by default masks duplicates except the first occurrence as True:

```
df.Group.duplicated()

#0    False
#1     True
#2     True
#3    False
#4     True
#5     True
#Name: Group, dtype: bool
```

To keep the one row per group edge case (won't be so efficient any more):

```
df[df.Group.duplicated() | df.Group.groupby(df.Group).transform('count').eq(1)]

# Group Value
#1    a     1
#2    a     2
#4    b     7
#5    b     8
```

Or:

```
df[df.Group.groupby(df.Group).transform(lambda x: (x.size == 1) | x.duplicated())]
# Group  Value
#1    a      1
#2    a      2
#4    b      7
#5    b      8
```

Comment: something wrong here, if it is unique , it also remove it. you can try add one more row c  11

Comment: @Wen Yep. Updated with the edge case.

Answer (score 2):

[If it is unique row , you want to keep it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119592/python-pandas-dropping-first-in-series-of-duplicates#comment83215840_48119592)

```
df.groupby('Group').Value.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:] if len(x)>1 else x).reset_index('Group')
Out[144]: 
  Group  Value
1     a      1
2     a      2
4     b      7
5     b      8
6     c     11
```

Data input

```
df
Out[138]: 
  Group  Value
0     a      0
1     a      1
2     a      2
3     b      6
4     b      7
5     b      8
6     c     11
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice from the top of your answer. I also learn about how you select groups!

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of first rows and drop it with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).  Thanks for Wen for the notice in the answer that we should keep rows that do not have duplicates and I learn from his/her approach to select groups that have duplicates.

```
grouped = df.reset_index().groupby("Group")["index", "Value"]
first_rows = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if len(x) > 1 else None).dropna()
index_first_rows = first_rows["index"]
df.drop(index_first_rows, axis="index")
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it should work

```
F = []
for names, frames in df.groupby('Group'):

    F.append(frames.sort_values('value').iloc[1:,:])

new_df = pd.concat(F)
```